# Inertiajs - Switch to another page locally

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs

I would like to know how to switch between different pages on the client side only, without inertia.visit().

I am using Laravel and Inertiajs.

I understand that props must be specified from the laravel side in order to move to another page.

Is there any way to switch pages without communication between client and server?

I want to switch pages only on the client side with the URL, not by switching components within the same page.

Comment: Great question. Did you ever work out how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you are asking for this, but InertiaJS has an alternative for manual visits - [the InertiaJS Link](https://inertiajs.com/links):

```html
<template>
  <Link href="/myPage" v-text="`Click me`" />
</template>

<script setup>
  import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
</script>
```

Logically, anyways you'll have to register a route in `routes/web.php`, else you'll get a 404:

```php
Route::get('/myPage', function () {
  return inertia('MyPage');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I know the way you showed me.

This time I would like to know how to transition pages without communicating with the server.

Comment: @nomemt not sure what you mean exactly, can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: For pages that don't need props, I don't want inertia requests just to switch pages

I want to switch pages only on the client side.